# What is the lowest Latency I can get between two cloud compute instances on EC2/GoogleCloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, google-cloud-platform, request, packet

I made 2 google cloud instances in the same region. I used one to ping the other, and I got rrt average = 0.4ms. I did the same thing with two ec2 instances and got similar results.

Is it possible to get faster times using any of google or amazon's services? maybe for the two instances to be in the same box?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to place both instances in the same [EC2 Placement Group Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html), which was designed for low-latency networking between instances.

As you mentioned in your question, you could also force both instances onto the "same box", but that will require [reserving the entire physical server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-hosts-overview.html) for your EC2 instances, which isn't cheap.

Answer (score 0):

There is no objective answer to the lowest possible achievable round-trip time.  As I am much more familiar with AWS, the remainder of this answer focuses there.

EC2 has three options that at least initially seem relevant; however, only one of them appears appropriate and useful for this purpose, on further analysis.

[*Dedicated Hosts*](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/) is the name of what you asked about -- multiple instances can run on the same host -- but these are marketed as a way to save licensing costs (where 3rd party software licenses are tied to CPU sockets or other hardware attributes) or regulatory compliance.  The literature doesn't mention latency.  It *seems like* a reasonable assumption that two instances sharing the same physical host might have excellent latency, but do they?  If the host has multiple network connections (and it seems reasonable that it would) then "the same host" may not be as meaningful as it sounds like it would be.

Dedicated hosts also have a significantly high cost, since you are preventing AWS from using that capacity for any other purpose.  If you test this, be sure you not only terminate the instances, but terminate the dedicated host hardware as well, since they *start* at $0.449/hour.

Another problem with dedicated hosts would be that if the host machine fails, all the instances running on it would also be expected to fail.  All hardware fails, eventually.

[*Dedicated Instances*](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/dedicated-instances/) are another way to potentially have two or more instances on the same hardware.  A dedicated instance is provisioned on host hardware that is reserved for exclusive use by your account, but there are multiple problems that prevent this from being useful, here.  Again, this is a compliance-oriented feature, so you don't have control (or visibility) of *which* host is hosting a given instance -- you only know that AWS had agreed (in exchange for a fee) not to provision instances from any AWS account other than your own on the same hardware that is running any of your dedicated instances.  Other (non-dedicated) instances in your account may also be provisioned on the same host hardware as your dedicated instance(s) but you can't see it.  Activating this feature incurs a $2/hour surcharge per region where you're using it (not per instance).

The recommended way to achieve low latency and redundant hardware is a *Cluster Placement Group*.

> Cluster placement groups are recommended for applications that benefit from low network latency, high network throughput, or both, and if the majority of the network traffic is between the instances in the group. To provide the lowest latency and the highest packet-per-second network performance for your placement group, choose an instance type that supports enhanced networking.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html#placement-groups-cluster

Be sure you note whether your selected instance type supports [enhanced networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html), since -- as noted above -- this may be important for achieving minimum latency.

There isn't a charge for the Cluster Placement Group feature.  You can typically add more instances to an existing placement group, later, but launching a new instance into an existing placement group fails if the requested placement can't be provided due to a lack of capacity in the infrastructure that is appropriately near to the existing instances in the group.  Stopping and starting the entire group may remedy this, but the recommendation is to launch all the instances in a group in a single launch request.